# error response from daemon: no such container: dionaea

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers, daemon

I am working on T-Pot 16.03 which is a bundle of honeypots working in dockerised format for research purposes. This is running on Ubunutu 14.04 .4 LTS.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCrWt.jpg

As you can see, container dionaea has stopped working for no reason at all. I did not modify anything from the machine in the last three days except for the fact that I let it run for 3-6hrs straight. I tried restarting the docker container but I was given the error:

Failed to kill container (dionaea) : Error response from daemon: No such container : dionaea

This was outputted when giving the command sudo docker restart dionaea

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling it by ID instead of name.

To see the container's ID, execute the command:

```
docker ps
```

It will show you an output similar to

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
399a864df5cc        dockercompose_db   "/entrypoint.sh "   About an hour ago   Up 5 minutes        8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49160->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49161->1521/tcp   dockercompose_db_1
```

Then you can take CONTAINER ID and use it like:

```
docker restart 399a864df5cc
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to explain this but when I removed old/unused containers/images, this error was solved.

```
docker ps -a
docker rm oldcontainer
docker images
docker rmi oldimage
```